# laravel 4 hybridauth on multiple routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, hybridauth

I'm just currently trying to switch from CodeIgniter to Laravel.

I have implemented the hybridouth method successful, but it seems to be only working for that route it's specified on.

I've tried searching for tutorials and examples but even they only show the auth is working on 1 route.

How can I give some function along to every route to check if a user is logged in?

Group for which the auth is needed.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    // ALL ROUTES WITH AUTH NEEDED
});
```

This seems to call the normal auth and i'm using the hybridauth

```
Route::get('social/{action?}', array("as" => "hybridauth", function($action = "")
{
if ($action == "auth") {
    try {
        Hybrid_Endpoint::process();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return Redirect::route('hybridauth');
    }
    return;
}
try {
    $socialAuth = new Hybrid_Auth(app_path() . '/config/hybridauth.php');
    $provider = $socialAuth->authenticate("facebook");
    $userProfile = $provider->getUserProfile();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}

echo "<pre>" . print_r( $userProfile, true ) . "</pre><br />";
}));
```

Comment: Can you post the code when you configure the route that work?

Comment: Added the code in my first post.

Followed from: [link](http://www.mrcasual.com/on/coding/laravel4-package-management-with-composer/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to run the request at every route, use a filter

```
App::before(function($request)
{
//check if user logged in here
});
```

or create filter and group your routes

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{

});
```

Comment: Thanks going to switch to that one. With the grouped route.